# Is network sharing information logged anywhere in windows?

Tags: windows, file-sharing, logging

My question is for Windows XP as well as Windows 7.

When I share a folder on a network by
*right clicking a folder>Properties>Sharing(tab)>Share this folder on the network*
does Windows log the information like when the folder was shared and who accessed it?

Is there any way to find if any folder was shared previously?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable auditing through a GPO or the Local Security Policy. Have a look here:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-how-to-audit-file-and-folder-access-to-improve-windows-2000-pro-security/

This article is written for Windows 2000, but the same settings still apply for Windows 7 / Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

By default, no. Folder permission changes need to be explicitly turned on either through GPO or the Local Security Policy.